# Creating Nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a main array and I want to create other arrays in the main array, as the sub arrays will have data for egg, baby, intraining.

I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing it?

The reason why I want to do it this way,is that, if I want to access the `egg`.`name` in the `digiList`array, I know it would work without any errors poping up when I do `console.log(digiList.egg.name)`

Currently the error I get is `Egg is not defined`

```
const digiList = [
 egg = [           
   {
     id:"blue",
     eggtype:"blue",
     digivolution:"Punimon",
     image:"../Images/Blue Egg - mobile.png"
    },        
],    

baby =[
 {
   id:"botamon",
   name:"Botamon",
   stage:"Baby",
   type:"Data",
   preDigivolution:["green"],
   digivolution:["Koromon"],
   image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/12-botamon.jpg"
  },

intraining = [
 {
  id:"koromon",
  name:"Koromon",
  stage:"In-training",
  type:"Data",
  preDigivolution:["Botamon"],
  digivolution:["Agumon","Gabumon","Kunemon"],
  image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/50-koromon.jpg"
 }
]
]

]
```

Comment: share the code you tried to solve the problem

Comment: This is my own code, its something I am creating from scratch. I just want to know if this is correct, so when I reference the array ```console.log(digiList.egg.name)```

Comment: you should to format question in this way.

[Input] -> [Expected output]  

and if you tried anything you should share that code as well , if you didn't write any code, you can share your thought process for the solution

Comment: We can achieve the same by this way : - 

   **const digiList = {
        "egg" : { id:"blue", name:"somename otherwise 'undefined" },
        "baby" : { id:"botamon", name:"Botamon"},
        "intraining" : { id:"koromon", name:"Koromon" }
    };   
    console.log( digiList.egg.name );**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not a valid array. If your goal is being able to access the data via do notation, eg. `digiList.egg.name` then using arrays is not how to get there. You would need to use objects. Assuming you have one object in each of the data elements, `egg`, `baby` and `intraining` then you would take the following approach:

```js
const 
    egg = { id:"blue", name:"somename otherwise 'undefined'", eggtype:"blue", digivolution:"Punimon", image:"../Images/Blue Egg - mobile.png" },
    baby = { id:"botamon", name:"Botamon", stage:"Baby", type:"Data", preDigivolution:["green"], digivolution:["Koromon"], image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/12-botamon.jpg" },
    intraining = { id:"koromon", name:"Koromon", stage:"In-training", type:"Data", preDigivolution:["Botamon"], digivolution:["Agumon","Gabumon","Kunemon"], image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/50-koromon.jpg" },
    
    digiList = { egg, baby, intraining };
    
    console.log( digiList.egg.name, digiList.baby.name, digiList.intraining.name );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const egg = { id:"blue", name:"somename otherwise 'undefined'", eggtype:"blue", digivolution:"Punimon", image:"../Images/Blue Egg - mobile.png" };
const baby = { id:"botamon", name:"Botamon", stage:"Baby", type:"Data", preDigivolution:["green"], digivolution:["Koromon"], image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/12-botamon.jpg" };
const intraining = { id:"koromon", name:"Koromon", stage:"In-training", type:"Data", preDigivolution:["Botamon"], digivolution:["Agumon","Gabumon","Kunemon"], image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/50-koromon.jpg" };
    
const digiList = { egg, baby, intraining };
    
console.log( digiList.egg.name );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a variable inside an array.

But you can declare it outside and then refer to it inside, e.g.

```js
let egg = 1
const digiList =  [
  egg = 2, egg=4, egg=egg*3
]

console.log(digiList)

// output: [2, 4, 12]
```

In your case you might refer to the answer given from **Lalit Tyagi**, it should fulfill your needs.

```js
const egg = { id:"blue", name:"somename otherwise 'undefined'", eggtype:"blue", digivolution:"Punimon", image:"../Images/Blue Egg - mobile.png" };
const baby = { id:"botamon", name:"Botamon", stage:"Baby", type:"Data", preDigivolution:["green"], digivolution:["Koromon"], image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/12-botamon.jpg" };
const intraining = { id:"koromon", name:"Koromon", stage:"In-training", type:"Data", preDigivolution:["Botamon"], digivolution:["Agumon","Gabumon","Kunemon"], image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/50-koromon.jpg" };
    
const digiList = { egg, baby, intraining };
    
console.log( digiList.egg.name );
```

Comment: We can also achieve the same by this way also.
    **const digiList = {
        "egg" : { id:"blue", name:"somename otherwise 'undefined" },
        "baby" : { id:"botamon", name:"Botamon"},
        "intraining" : { id:"koromon", name:"Koromon" }
    };   
    console.log( digiList.egg.name );**

Answer (score 0):

*after I read the comments, it was right to say something about what I was doing. here is the thing, based on the es6 and beyond array may contain an array, literals, objects, and another array and inside the array, it is not advisable to declare a variable. so in the end, you know array destructuring and object destructuring to use them. by the way, I appetite for your constructive comments.*

```js
   const digiList = [
 [           
   {
     id:"blue",
     eggtype:"blue",
     digivolution:"Punimon",
     image:"../Images/Blue Egg - mobile.png"
    },        
],    

[
 {
   id:"botamon",
   name:"Botamon",
   stage:"Baby",
   type:"Data",
   preDigivolution:["green"],
   digivolution:["Koromon"],
   image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/12-botamon.jpg"
  },

 [
 {
  id:"koromon",
  name:"Koromon",
  stage:"In-training",
  type:"Data",
  preDigivolution:["Botamon"],
  digivolution:["Agumon","Gabumon","Kunemon"],
  image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/50-koromon.jpg"
 }
]
]
]

const[egg, baby] = digiList;

const[,intraining] = baby;
```

Comment: it would be better if you can provide a bit more context to your answer as why and what changes you have made.

Comment: it is always better to decorate your answer with context as of what and where and why the answer will help OP.